# Define a resource of Service module, But 'access callback' cannot work

Tags: users, services

This following is my resource:

For clearly read, I delete some line.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_services_resources().
 */

function baidu_push_services_services_resources() {
  $resources = array();

  $resources['message']['actions']['send'] = [
    'file' => array(
      'type' => 'inc',
      'module' => 'baidu_push_services',
      'name' => 'baidu_push_services',
    ),
    'access callback' => '_message_access',
    'callback' => 'baidu_push_services_send',
    'args' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'uid',
        'type' => 'string',
        'source' => 'data',
        'optional' => FALSE,
      ),
  ];

  return $resources;
}
```

In order to test my `'access callback'` function will be invoked, I always return `FALSE` in my `'access callback'` function:

```
function _message_access($op = 'view', $args = array()) {
  return FALSE;
}
```

But when I try to use `curl` command line to test with no SESSION and no Token, but It work!(return the right result to me), Did that mean `'access callback'` not be invoked?

So I try to use `drush cc all` to clear cache, But still above problem.

Comment: Are you working with a permission hook? Are you calling curl with authentication or can your service be accessed by anonymous? I'm guessing it's a permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your access callback in the same file? If not, you'd have to add: "access callback file" to your definition, and point to it.

I'd also clear cache within Drupal, as I've seen drush cc all not always clear all caches.

Also, I'd name-space your access callback function, as it could be conflicting with something else in the system. _message_access is a pretty generic name. You should rename it to: _baidu_push_services_message_access().

Otherwise, your syntax looks correct.

Or, if you solved your issue, perhaps post it in here, to help others.

Comment: thanks for your help, I am try to re-download new drupal and services module, and put my code in, but still not work. So, I am consider i should switch to another language/framework?

Comment: access callback in the same file? yes!